# Windows Equivalent for sys/mman.h

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, porting

I'm encountering issues when trying to compile my C code on Win64. More specifically, the compiler cannot find the `sys/mman.h` header, which I understand is found in Unix environments only.

I already know this is deals with memory allocation.

Is there an equivalent for Windows I can use in order to port the code (first time trying)?

Code in that causes issues:

```
/* Allocate memory required by processes */
buf = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
if (!buf)
{
    perror("Error");
    free (buf);
    return -3;
}

/* Lock down pages mapped to processes */
puts("Locking down processes.");
if(mlockall (MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE) < 0)
{
    perror("mlockall");
    free (buf);
    return -4;
}
```

Comment: not directly, WINAPI has it's own functions that are included via `windows.h` that do the same things, but those functions are POSIX only and are not available on windows. So the question as asked cannot be answered because there is no equivalent header.

Comment: @Mgetz while i agree that natively it doesnt, the win32 library i linked in my response should do the trick.

Comment: @Mekap or they could just do it the native way with [`VirtualAllocEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890(v=vs.85).aspx) and cousins

Comment: @Mgetz yeah of course, editing my response to fit that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at the [mman-win32 library](https://code.google.com/p/mman-win32/). But as @Mgetz pointed out, a more simple way is to look at the [`VirtualAllocEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions and try to adapt your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, however the compiler is having trouble with the mlockall function. Can this be replaced by the `VirtualAllocEx` function or does that just allocate memory (a bit like malloc above, which seems to be working)? (I know I didn't specify this in the original question, which I probably should have done).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the issue by using g++ under cygwin, making sure the g++ came from the cygwin installation (the same version specified from the installer) and not the current compiler under windows.