# VS Code Incude Headerfile

Tags: c, include

I know this question was answered often on this plattform but the suggestions didn't work. I want to include `#include <sys/mman.h>` to my C-file. This does not work because the settings of include Path are not changed. I followed the common suggestion of going to the json c_cpp_properties.json file and include the path by myself

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**", 
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

But the c-file where I want to add `#include <sys/mman.h>` still says that I should change the include Path settings.

Comment: Notice that `<sys/mman.h>`  is POSIX. I don't know if Windows has it. See [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Comment: Is there no way of including it in vs code on windows?

Comment: I never coded for Windows, but according to rumors the primitive to expand the virtrual address space could be different. Consider (if allowed) to use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/memory-allocation. Or even install [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop

Comment: If you specifically use `mmap` then you would need it. The WSL option mentioned by @BasileStarynkevitch would then be nice. If you just need similar functionality, take a look at the `VirtualAlloc` and/or `CreateFileMapping` functions in the Windows API.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660492/windows-equivalent-for-sys-mman-h